# Why storyboard objects with constraints do not display properly at run time?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have added to a custom tableView cell two labels and one button. Label named *Value* must be a self sizing label. The problem is that the objects are overlapping over each other at run time.  I have been trying all sorts of constraints for the past few hours and I can't get it to display properly. If this question is not relevant for other, after I get some help, I will delete it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 75
  }
```

I have added the following constraints
 - cell size is 75

- titleLabel:
  Top Space to: SuperView 13
  Leading Space to: SuperView: 8
  Width: 175
  Height: 21
- valueLabel
  Top Space to: editButton 7
  Bottom Space to: SuperView 12.5
  Leading Space to: SuperView 0
  Trailling Space to: editButton 0
- editButton
  Top Space to: SuperView 13
  Width: 48
  Height: 21
  Trailling Space to: SuperView 0

  Main.storyboard 
  [image: Main.storyboard]

  Run time
  [image: Run time]

Comment: Does Xcode show any constraints conflicts?

Comment: Any messages in console at runtime? Any warnings in View Debugger at runtime?

Comment: @matt There are no warnings or constraint conflicts displayed in the debugger at run time.

Comment: That's very odd, and I find it hard to believe. It seems to me that you have not told the truth about something — perhaps about your constraints, or perhaps about what the View Debugger tells you. If you are using the View Debugger properly, it tells you exactly what your constraints are and why things are being positioned where they are. That should be enough to figure it out.

Comment: For example, why is the Edit button off on the left when you have said that the constraint pins it to the right? It makes no sense, unless there is some kind of fundamental ambiguity or something is going on that you are not telling us about. — Can you reduce the problem to a very simple example project (e.g. just one row of sample table data, where the one cell displays the issue) and post it somewhere?

Comment: @matt I have created a simple project which reproduces almost same behaviour. https://github.com/bibscy/simpleApp If you set `TestTableView` as initial view controller, the labels and button will be displayed properly. But, if you set `TestViewController` as initial view controller, it will start misbehaving. Note* I did not implement CosmosView in `TestViewController`, FeedbackCell as it is shown in my original question. Basically, it starts misbehaving when more cells of different sizes are added to the tableView

Comment: Cool, thanks, let me take a quick look here...

Comment: Okay but (1) I do see a major conflict warning in the console at runtime, and (2) I don't see the stuff you show in your screen shot — all I see is that the ContentCell doesn't get the right height, but the Edit button is off to the right, the labels do not overlap, etc.

Comment: And the reason the ContentCell doesn't get the right height is obvious: you implemented `heightForRowAt` to curtail its height.

Comment: Okay, so I deleted your `heightForRow` implementation, and I modified your `numberOfRowsInSection` so that for sections 0, 2, 3 we return `0`,  thus suppressing the other cells and only the ContentCell will appear. And guess what? No errors, no problems. We see just the ContentCell and it looks just fine.

Comment: And then I removed the width constraints from the labels in the other three cell prototypes and restored them to the interface, and it's all good. So I absolutely cannot reproduce the issue you show in your screenshot.

Comment: See https://youtu.be/q3lx5lldxWI - looks fine to me.

Comment: @matt I see. Let me check further and get back to you.

Comment: Well, my work is done. You posted an example that you claimed would allow me to reproduce the issue, and I couldn't reproduce it. I'm ready to vote to close as unreproducible.

Comment: @matt please see a video from my original project https://youtu.be/CFUEwxqyHbE . After I add the button to the cell, set the constraints, it jumps to the left.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "add the button". In code? In the storyboard? All I know is what you sent me. I asked you to show me the problem happening and you _didn't_. The end, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: In the video I sent you earlier, in Interface Builder, I add a button to the custom tableView cell and then I assign to it: Top, Right, Bottom, Width and Height constraints. At run time, the button will move to the left side of the scene instead of staying pinned to the right as it was supposed to.

Comment: If you can codify this into a project that _demonstrates the problem_ we can talk again...

Comment: @matt I have been unable reproduce the problem in a new project. In my original project I deleted the whole UIViewController scene, hooked up the same controls with the same constraints and it works. Thank you for your help. Please advise if I should delete the question I am not sure if it is relevant to others.

Comment: Great that you solved it! It would also be great if we actually knew what the problem was. But we don't; I still think this is an unreproducible issue, therefore, and probably should be closed as such, or you could just delete it. No harm, no foul!

Comment: @matt I found an explanation in the docs. It makes no sense for my use case because I deleted all views off the content view cell and added them again with the same constraints as in the project I sent you with no result and then I asked for help here.... Apple docs * Odd and unexpected layouts often occur when views with invisible backgrounds (like buttons or labels) are accidentally stretched beyond their intrinsic content size. The actual problem may not be obvious, because the text simply appears in the wrong location. To prevent unwanted stretching, increase the content-hugging priority.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1

Comment: I don't think that's it. The text of the button did not appear in the wrong location; the button _itself_ appeared in the wrong location, and there was nothing wrong with its size (we know because its background is _not_ invisible).

Comment: @matt, last time we talked, I couldn't provide a reproductible issue for this question, but now I have another questions and I can reproduce the issue. There is a github test project in the new question. Thanks for helping me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579137

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix. Go to your Storyboard, click on the label and go to the Size Inspector. You should see near the bottom **Content Hugging Priority** and **Content Compression Resistance Priority**. Edit these values for your needs.

Comment: could you advise what values I should assign to each object for Content Hugging Priority and Content Compression Resistance Priority ? Also, why do I need to set them in this particular instance? Thanks

Comment: @bibscy These values determine which images you want to have priority over. If something needs to be compressed as it fills up too much space this can be used. However, another way to set your constraints is relative to other buttons - which in this case may be easier.

Comment: @bibscy Click on your label, then click **Add new constraints** at the bottom. Then click the little arrows on Top, Trailing etc. and set the values. These will be relative.