# How to resize textLabel in segmented control in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol

In a `UIViewController` there is a Segmented Controller placed at the top of the view. Constraints: left: 0, right:0, top: 0, height:90.

Every time a `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification is posted, segmented control should update it's view with the newest date by calling `func updateUI()`

On first load, when `viewDidLoad` is called the text in each segment is displayed as expected.
   However, if the app goes in background, when it comes back in foreground, the label of the segmented control does not accommodate the text and shows 3 dots... after.  See attachment and gif below.

Scope: update segmented control title for each segment every time `.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification is posted.
    Public Github project https://github.com/bibscy/testProject

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var stringDates = [String]()

   var dateNow: Date {
     return Date()
   }
      @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

       func updateUI() {
    //create string dates and set the title of for each segment in segmented control
          self.getNextDays()  
     }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUI), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

     UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0

      self.getNextDays()
   }
}


  extension ViewController {

//for each segment, construct a string date with the currentDate() being first, followed by 5 consecutive days
func getNextDays()  {

    stringDates.removeAll() //clear any previous data

    for i in 0...5 {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let today = dateNow
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        if i == 0 {
            let dayComponent = Calendar.current.component(.weekday,from: today)
            let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: today) //Int
            let dayString = dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[dayComponent-1] //Symbol


            let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: today)
            let monthSymbol = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols[month-1]
            let dayMonthString =  dayString + " " + String(day) + " " + monthSymbol
            stringDates.append(dayMonthString)


        } else {
            var components = DateComponents()
            components.weekday = i

            let nextDay = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: today)
            let nextDayComponent = Calendar.current.component(.weekday,from: nextDay!)
            let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: nextDay!)
            let dayString = dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[nextDayComponent-1] // Symbol


            let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: nextDay!)
            let monthSymbol = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols[month-1]
            let dayMonthString = dayString + " " + String(day) + " " + monthSymbol
            stringDates.append(dayMonthString)
        }
    }


      //set the title for each segment from stringDates array
       for value in 0...5 {
         self.segmentedControl.setTitle(self.stringDates[value], forSegmentAt: value)
      }
   } //end of getNextDays()  
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: hide this `extension Claim { 

     func updateUI() {

     self.getNextDays()
   //  UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0
   }` and check

Comment: @Anbu.karthik If I comment out in extension `self.getNextDays()` and  `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0 } `, the text will be rendered in each segment as expected. Basically, the label does not get resized if I call `self.getNextDays()` . Which in turn means that when `self.segmentedControl.setTitle(self.stringDates[value], forSegmentAt:` is called inside `self.getNextDays()` , the label is not properly resized, that's my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is only reproduced in 10.3 iOS version.
Solution:

Store initial properties of a segmented label:

```
fileprivate var height: CGFloat! 
fileprivate var width: CGFloat!
```

Add to ViewDidLoad just before `getNextDays`:

```
let label = segmentedControl.subviews[0].subviews[0] as! UILabel 
height = label.frame.height 
width = label.frame.width
```

Set text :

```
for value in 0...5 {
   segmentedControl.setTitle(stringDates[value], forSegmentAt: value)
}
```

And fix frames after that:

```
let labels = segmentedControl.subviews.map{ $0.subviews[1] } as! [UILabel]
    labels.forEach { (label) in
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        let frame = label.frame
        label.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: width, height: height)
    }
```

[Sample code with some crash protection](https://github.com/llkenny/testProject)

Comment: I am running on Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b. Setting height for segmented control in Interface builder is not an possible. All constraint boxes are grayed, not selectable. See screenshot https://imgur.com/a/W8nGJ4i

Comment: The reason why I could not set constraints is because the segmented control was placed on a Navigation Bar. Thanks

Comment: As i see, you place it in the Navigation Item. Try to place it in the main view.

Comment: When app starts for the first time, I get same result as shown in your picture above. But, when app goes, in background and then in foreground, text looks badly on the label. Basically, when app goes in foreground, I am calling `updateUI()`, which calls `getNextDays()` which in turn calls `segmentedControl.setTitle(self.stringDates[value], forSegmentAt: value)` and this is where it goes wrong again. Did you run a simple project in simulator?

Comment: Yes, i did. I think the problem is in autolayout conflict with a tableView or a safeArea. Try to implement clear ViewController with the segmented controller without a tableView.

Comment: Also, you can try to remove `updateUI()`. The problem is likely to remain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171993/discussion-between-bibscy-and-llkenny).

Comment: @Ikenny One more problem I didn't notice yesterday. The dates are now displayed in descending order in my project, rather than ascending as it should be https://imgur.com/a/3uU4mDq

Comment: @bibscy Labels are inversed. Take a look at this commit https://github.com/llkenny/testProject/commit/a62bff62c0c4149e5f608fb34ba6ac8442f3da65

Comment: There is another problem. Start the test project app. Click on the segment at index 2, reading Fri 1 Jun https://imgur.com/a/yahYpeP . Now background the app and bring it back to foreground by tapping the icon in the simulator https://imgur.com/a/VuKGbP5. You will see that Fri 1 Jun has jumped at index 0 and order of the dates is mixed up. Please note that `func updateUI` is called by the observer when app is in foreground.

Comment: Yes, you're right... Perhaps setTitle method does some other internal stuff and manual set text is not so simple. I'll think about the solution a little more.

Comment: @bibscy Please try this commit: https://github.com/llkenny/testProject/commit/22758c809ed1d3d9c3896b607fbbe89c9f23bbc8
Keep in mind that it is dangerous to use in production. Force unwraps and hard coded numbers are not good. Here is should be `guard` statements.

Comment: Do you mean that I should put `guard` statements in the implementation you have done? I've tested it and it works. Please update your answer when you get the time.

Comment: I updated the answer and you can check the last commit on GitHub. There's some crash protection added. This is what i meant.

Comment: I have updated at my end too. In the future, I think I will use a horizontal UIPickerView. However, I am sure that others will find your answer very helpful. Many thanks